# To get result in the same line where you input values then taken up by scanf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

i study c programming via a book "c programming with problem solving by jacqueline and keith". and i use turbo c compiler.. i am a beginner in all this so please dont laugh.. there was a question in the book which prints out the employees id(you have to input the id and number of hours he has worked and the rate) and calculate the mans pay.. in this while loop is used.. there is a variation to this where you get the result in a tabular form and in the same line where you input the number of hours and the rate used by scanf.. when we use printf to print the result it comes in the next line.. how to get the result in the same line as the line where scanf values are inputted.. help me please

Comment: suggestion1 : Avoid turbo c; 
suggestion2 : Always supplement code you have already written with the question you are asking

Comment: suggestion 3 ...try ... to ... not ... sound ... so ... *aargh*

Comment: Curious, what computer are you using with Turbo C?  BTW: Posting code is more meaningful to Stack Overflow the posting text.

Answer (score 0):

First, turbo c is really old. Even if you're a beginner I'd recommend gcc (MinGW) or Code::Blocks.
Anyways - scanf automatically goes down to the next line as the input ends with the Enter key BUT you can manipulate it this way(Example would be getting a math sum trick and writing the answer in the same line - it's really simple and short on purpose):

```
int num1, num2;
scanf("%d+%d", &num1, &num2); //input would be "number"+"number".
system("cls"); //when working with gcc(MinGW) or any shell using compiler. With turbo C just use clrscr(); - in dos.h if I'm not wrong.
printf("%d+%d=%d", num1, num2, num1+num2);
```

And that's it, a pretty simple trick.